# interfacing Bash/Java/MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, bash, sockets

Current setup:

1. Bash script runs a for loop
2. Each run through loop executes Java script with several command line args
3. Java makes connection with MySQL
4. Java sends insert statements to MySQL

I'm concerned this is not very efficient. Each time through the bash script Java starts again and re-connects to the database. How can this be improved? Maybe Java open a socket and accept incoming messages from bash script? Idk how to do this, or to make sure that onyl the bash script can talk through this socket (and not some malicious script/user).

Any ideas? My java code is below.

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

            String arg1 = args[0];
            String arg2 = args[1];
            String arg3 = args[2];
            String arg4 = args[3];
            int arg5 = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
            int arg6 = Integer.parseInt(args[5]);
            int arg7 = Integer.parseInt(args[6]);

            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://sql.domain.com/table_name";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "password";

           /*
           * SOME LOGIC ...
           */

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

                // parameterized SQL statement
                preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("insert into some_table values (default, ?, ?);");

                // Parameters start with 1 (bogus inserts, ignore these for purpose of question)
                preparedStatement.setString(1, "THE NAME");
                preparedStatement.setString(2, "A VALUE");
                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

            } finally {
                try {
                    if (rs != null) {
                        rs.close();
                    }
                    if (st != null) {
                        st.close();
                    }
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.close();
                    }

                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
                    lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: does the bash script have to initiate your code? why can't the loop be run in your java logic?

Comment: What's the need for the bash script at all? Looks to me that you can implement everything on Java and perhaps have a Thread checking for something to happen before executing the insert statements.

Comment: well if java can execute bash commands well, then yes. something like this (pulled from google): `Runtime r = Runtime.getSystemRuntime();
r.exec("whatever you want to run");`

Comment: You can convert all the things bash is doing into plain Java.  No need to call an external program to do it.  This is also more efficient than starting lots of programs.

Comment: Or why bother with the java part at all and just use a "here" document? This one starts Oracle sqlplus, but same deal would apply: sqlplus $userid/$password$identifier 2>&1 <<! |tee -a $LOG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good option would be to move the loop into the Java code, as others have suggested.

An alternative, and i think something that would be a traditional unix approach, would be to change your shell script loop to echo these arguments to standard output, and pipe that output into your script, which would then read them from its standard input.

So, if you currently do:

```
for i in a b c d e
do
    java -jar myprogram.jar foo.$i bar.$i baz.$i qux.$i 1 2 3
done
```

You could change it to:

```
for i in a b c d e
do
    echo foo.$i bar.$i baz.$i qux.$i 1 2 3
done | java -jar myprogram.jar
```

With your java code changing to something like:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = line.split(" "); // this could be done more robustly

        String arg1 = words[0];
        String arg2 = words[1];
        String arg3 = words[2];
        String arg4 = words[3];
        int arg5 = Integer.parseInt(words[4]);
        int arg6 = Integer.parseInt(words[5]);
        int arg7 = Integer.parseInt(words[6]);

        // then carry on as before
    }
}
```

This is easier than using a socket. It is also more secure, because only your script has access to the Java subprocess's standard input.

Answer (score 3):

How about if you just wrote a loop in your main that does what the bash script loop does?  You might show us the script, but Java can do anything bash does.

**Update**

It would *really* help if you showed us the bash script.  What you're describing sounds like you're doing

```
for i in a b c d e
do
   java -jar myprogram.jar $i
done
```

or following a similar pattern.  Why not do the loop in Java to run the Java program, doing all the work in Java?  All you really would need is to add

```
foreach (arg : argv){
    // call your original program
}
```

or something very close to that.

Comment: yeah that's a good point. something like this (googled)? `Runtime r = Runtime.getSystemRuntime();
r.exec("whatever you want to run");`